# does different domain for inverse trigonometric function give different definite integral?

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

$\int_{-1}^1 {\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x^2}} \; dx$

becomes

$\int_{\tan^{-1}-1}^{\tan^{-1}1} {\theta} \; d\theta$

by substituting $x = \tan(\theta)$

different domain
$\left(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right)$ or
$\left(-\frac\pi2 + \pi, \frac\pi2 + \pi\right)$
for the function tan would give different answer.

I think they must be equal, and I am missing something..

I can't see which statement is causing the problem.
when I set the domain of than to be $\left(-\frac\pi2 + \pi, \frac\pi2 + \pi\right)$

$x=\tan\theta$
$dx = \sec^2(\theta) \ d \theta$
$\tan^{-1}1 = \pi + \frac\pi4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\tan^{-1}$ is defined as the inverse of $\tan$ restricted to a certain domain. If you change the domain to which you restrict $\tan$, you change all the values of the function $\tan^{-1}$, not only in the integral after substitution but also in the integral before substitution. It should not be a surprise that the integrals of two different functions may have different values.

Usually the function $\tan^{-1}$ is defined by restricting the domain of $\tan$ specifically to $\left(-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right),$ not to any other possible domain. That's what makes $\tan^{-1}$ a function with an agreed-upon definition. That definition is presumably the one intended in the first integral.

---

I suppose the confusion may be that in many trigonometric substitutions, the choice of the domain of the new variable is arbitrary and you will get the same answer regardless. The reason this usually works is that when you make the substitution $x = f(x)$ where $f$ is some trigonometric function, the inverse of $f$ is not actually defined in the original integral itself and you get to choose the inverse you want. In this case, $\tan^{-1}$ is explicitly named in the original integral and that's what you have to integrate.
By definition, $$\tan^{-1} 1 = \frac\pi4 \neq \pi + \frac\pi4.$$

Comment: thanks, but then, I can't see how I should modify the derivation to cope with the different $tan^{-1}$ depending on the domain. by changing domain, I'm not allowed to say =() ?

Comment: You can say $x = \tan\theta.$ This transforms a definite integral whose value is $0$ by symmetry (according to the standard definition of the arc tangent) into another definite integral whose value is $0.$ There is no other answer. If you want to define an alternative function that is not $\tan^{-1}$ but is the inverse of $\tan$ restricted to a different interval, you are free to integrate that function as you like, but that has nothing to do with the integral you wrote in the question.

Comment: Ok, I guess I see your point after drawing the tan and arctan with different domains, you can define tan over different domain, but inverse tan would be different function depending on the domain, so it's just a matter of the definition what arctan 's domain is.

Answer (score 1):

> $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 {\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{1+x^2}} \; dx=\displaystyle\int_{\tan^{-1}-1}^{\tan^{-1}1} {\theta} \; d\theta$
>
> by substituting $x = \tan(\theta)$

To be clear: here the substitution is $$\theta=\arctan(x),$$ where $\arctan$ (that is, $\tan^{-1}$) is generally understood to have principal range $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right).$

> different domain  $\left(-\frac\pi2 + \pi, \frac\pi2 + \pi\right)$   for the function
> tan would give different answer.

Sure, the substitution $$x=\tan(\theta)\quad \bigg(\theta\in\left(-\frac\pi2 + \pi, \frac\pi2 + \pi\right)\bigg)$$ is valid too, and is equivalent to $$\theta=\pi+\arctan(x);$$ this gives \begin{align}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^2} \,\mathrm dx&=\int_{\pi+\arctan(-1)}^{\pi+\arctan^{-1}(1)} \theta-\pi \, \mathrm d\theta\\&=0\\\\&=\int_{\arctan(-1)}^{\arctan(1)} \theta \, \mathrm d\theta,\end{align} as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you define $g(x):=f(x)+\pi$ where $f:=\tan^{-1}$ is the usual bijection $\Bbb R\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2),$ then
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{g(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_{-1}^1\frac{f(x)}{1+x^2}dx+\frac{\pi^2}2$$
and
$$\int_{g(-1)}^{g(1)}\theta d\theta=\frac12\left((f(1)+\pi)^2-(f(-1)+\pi)^2\right)=\int_{f(-1)}^{f(1)}\theta d\theta+\frac{\pi^2}2.$$